# Jenkins build fails when executing shell

Tags: shell, powershell, jenkins

I am trying to run a `powershell` script called `filemove.ps1` through `Jenkins`. I have put the path to the file in the Execute Shell section like this

powershell.exe -file "\BUILD\AutomatedDelivery\FileMove\FileMove.ps1"

Which is the location of the file on the network. Do I need to call something in order to make this run? As of now, I am getting a failed build with the error,

"line 2: powershell.exe command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Build is the name of the server, you need double backslash \\ before it. 
if its not, you need to put the server\share